# Routing Distance One way versus reverse direction

Tags: here-api

I am using the Here API to calculate distance between two coordinates.  The mileage in one direction is sometimes significantly different then in the other direction.  I assume this is because we are using a set date/time and is taking into account historical traffic patterns.  Are there other factors that could be impacting the difference?  Below is an call we are making:

https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=app_id&app_code=app_code&mode=shortest;car;traffic:disabled&departure=2019-03-04T09:00:00&waypoint0=lat,long&waypoint1=lat,long

Answer (score 0):

Many attributes affect route calculation which can be specified as per the use case. To check the dependent factors, please refer

http://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-calculate-route.html